# Using a collection and error handling to find new item numbers

Tags: excel, search, collections, vba

I get monthly reports of inventory sales. There are items added to the system regularly, and I find these by their unique ID numbers. I have an excel file with a list of all the item numbers and descriptions and a few other attributes.

My goal - download an excel file with all the items sold last month. If there are new items, add those to the existing list.

I am using something Siddharth Rout has posted on a previous answer, the relevant code looks like this:

```
dim col as collection
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ItemList
    For x = 3 To lastrowIL
        On Error Resume Next
        col.Add .Range("A" & x).Value, CStr(.Range("A" & x).Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next x
End With
With Monthly
.Range("AH3:AH" & lastrowM).Value = "New"
On Error Resume Next
    For y = 3 To lastrowM
        col.Add .Range("B" & y).Value, CStr(.Range("B" & y).Value)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then .Range("AH" & y).Value = "Old"
        Err.Clear
    Next y
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

the concept is that if you enter the same item ID twice, the same key will be used and there will be an error message which will change "new" to "old"

**The problem:** All additions to the collection are causing errors, thereby changing all "New" to "Old"

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out the problem by adding a watch to the err.number object.

I did not declare the collection as **New collection**
(or declare the collection and then set it as New collection)

fixed that and I fixed the "old" vs "new" indication.